# How to modify binomial tree to incorporate one more asset?

Tags: finance-mathematics, asset-pricing, quantitative

I wonder, what would happen if we use the binomial tree to price exchange option, an option to exchange one asset for another at the expiry date. Payoff is $\max(S_1-S_2,0)$

For instance, I have two assets whose payoff are the following:
$\begin{bmatrix}1.1&0.9\\1.1&1.1\\0.9&1.1\end{bmatrix}$, and $S_0^1=100$ and $S_0^2=95$, risk free rate is $R_f=4\%$ and $T=6$

How to deal with the one more dimension? My intuition is to use the binomial tree as usual. However, it is difficult to tell how many possible paths lead to a payoff, given that I have listed all possible combination of payoffs of asset 1 and 2.

Comment: Why do you keep deleting your old questions and then re-posting almost identical ones? https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/43846/

Comment: what is the "payoff" of an asset ? I don't understand your notation sorry.

Comment: @Ezy the matrix is the possible return.each column is one asset each row is one scenario

Comment: well what you are describing starts to look more like Monte-Carlo than a binomial tree. Besides it does not make sense to simulate multi assets without taking into account the correlation structure between those. So I am not convinced that what you are trying to do is very helpful.

Comment: @Ezy Yeah, there are three possible return between two assets, If I just use the return given, the correlation will be -0.5, then how should I proceed from here

Comment: @veryBigman use monte-carlo, or alternatively just specify the terminal 2d distribution of your 2 assets and do numerical integration of the payoff. Probably the formula exists somwhere for this simple case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under Black-Scholes assumption for the 2 assets $S_1$ and $S_2$ with volatilities $\sigma_{1,2}$ and correlation $\rho$ the value of this option has an explicit expression which is the [Margrabe formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margrabe%27s_formula)

To quote the result explicitly

Introducing $\sigma = \sqrt{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 - 2 \sigma_1\sigma_2\rho}$, Margrabe's formula states that the fair price for the option at time 0 and expiry $T$ is:

$$e^{-q_1 T}S_1(0) N(d_1) - e^{-q_2 T}S_2(0) N(d_2)$$

where $q_1,q_2$ are the expected dividend rates of the prices $S_1,S_2$ under the appropriate risk-neutral measure, $N$ denotes the cumulative distribution function for a normal distribution,

$$d_1 = (\ln (S_1(0)/S_2(0)) + (q_2 - q_1 + \sigma^2/2)T)/ \sigma\sqrt{T}$$, 
$$d_2 = d_1 - \sigma\sqrt{T}$$